# Does every tensor norm satisfy one half of the crossnorm property

Tags: functional-analysis, tensor-products

Suppose $(H,\|\cdot\|_{H})$ and $(G,\|\cdot\|_{G})$ are normed vector spaces. Suppose $\|\cdot\|$ is a norm on their algebraic tensor space $H\otimes G$. Do we have
$$
\|h\otimes g\|\leq C\|h\|_{H}\|g\|_{G}
$$
for some $C<\infty$

Comment: Do you want $\|\cdot\|$ to induce the same topology as the product norm? If two norms induce the same topology they are equivalent and that inequality holds.

Comment: @s.harp what is the product norm on a tensor product?

Comment: To prevent further clarification requests: I don't want to pose any assumptions on $\|\cdot\|$. I want to know if it is even possible to define a norm on a tensor space that does not satisfy this property.

Comment: Apparently its called cross norm: $\|x\| =\inf\{\sum_n \|a_n \| \cdot \|b_n\| \mid x = \sum_n a_n \otimes b_n\}$ defines a norm on the algebraic tensor space.

Comment: For a simple counterexample take $G=\mathbb C$ and $H$ the vector space of finite linear combinations of $\{e_i\}_{i\in\mathbb N}$ with $\mathscr l^\infty$ norm. Then $G\otimes H = H$, and by taking the $\mathscr l^1$ norm on $H$ you have there can exist no number C $\|x\|_1≤C\|x\|_\infty $ for all $x \in H$.

Comment: You are right. But I also found a proof that a counterexample is impossible if we are dealing with Banach spaces

Comment: that is very interesting, can you write it as an answer?

Comment: @s.harp this is proven around Lemma 4.33 in Hackbusch's "Tensor spaces and numerical tensor calculus" http://www.springer.com/us/book/9783642280269 Let me know if you don't have access, then I'll try my best and summarize it.

Comment: It is related to the fact that bilinear forms that are continuous in each variable separately are automatically jointly continuous, when the variables are elements of Banach spaces. According to Hackbusch this even holds when only one entry is a Banach space. I currently can't see how this does not contradict your counterexample.